# concatenating the two column values of different rows into one in teradata

Tags: teradata

I have table with the below data in teradata database

cstmr_id | name
1         | aaaaaa
1         | bbbbbb
2         | cccccc
2         | dddddd

I want the output to be like 
1 | aaaaaa,bbbbbb
2 | cccccc,dddddd

The output should be written to another table.
All this needs to be done in teradata.

Thanks in Advance,
Nikhila

Answer (score 1):

What's your Teradata release? Are XML services installed?

```
SELECT cstmr_id,  
   RTRIM(XMLAGG(name || ','
          ORDER BY name
        ) (VARCHAR(1000)),',')
FROM tab
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: thanks for this. Its working :). But can you tell me how to redirect the output into table again

Comment: @nikhilareddy: `INSERT INTO target SELECT ...`?