# Concatenating different columns and rows in Teradata

Tags: string, concatenation, teradata

I have two columns with data like this-

```
aaaaa   bbbbb

ccccc   ddddd

ddddd   eeeee
```

and I want to display my results as:

```
aaaaa-bbbbb;ccccc-ddddd;ddddd-eeeee
```

and so on. Concatenated into one long string.
How should I go about doing this in Teradata?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658113/concatenating-the-two-column-values-of-different-rows-into-one-in-teradata

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
Field 1 ||'-' || Field 2
FROM Database.Tablename ;
```